# JPQL JOIN query number of rows with corresponding value (for multiple columns)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, jpql

Consider these two tables

AverageGame Table

```
firstGame   secondGame  thirdGame
   10         20           30
```

Person Table

```
Person  first second  third
Bob      10     10      30
Bob      20     10      30
Bob      10     20      30
```

I am trying to return the number of times bob scores the same value as the average from the AverageGame table (e.g how many times he got 10 on first, 20 on second and 30 on third)
The result should be

```
[2,1,3]
```

Can anybody advise me how to do this as I can only do it for one column currently, any help is greatly appreciated thanks

Comment: do you need a `sql` solution?

Comment: Hi vkp preferably looking for jpql but sql could help as I can attempt to implement that instead thanks for formatting my question can you also tell me how you did that?

Answer (score 0):

That is a bit weird. Here is my approach:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1a3720/2

```
SELECT person, 
  SUM(IF(`first` = firstGame,1,0)) firstCount,
  SUM(IF(`second` = secondGame,1,0)) secondCount,
  SUM(IF(`third` = thirdGame,1,0)) thirdCount
FROM Person
LEFT JOIN AverageGame
ON 1
GROUP BY person
```

But my question is What do you expect should happen when  `AverageGame` table has more then 1 record?

Comment: I know it seems a bit weird but only solution for the problem. Thanks for your help I will give it a go this evening. As for your question, the averageGame table has another column as primary key which will represent the location of the game but the values for each location will never change